# Paginate using javascript

Tags: javascript, pagination

Following is the static html of the table. i dyanamically insert table based on the no of data i get(data.length) value that i get from the ajax call. 
Now i need to insert pagination in this where only 5 tables been allowed and if it exceeds to 6th, dyanamically pagination should happen where the values in the footer should increase by one( << < 1 2 > >> ).

```
<table id="myTable">
  <tbody id="tBody">
   <td>
   <tr>sample values</tr>
   <tr>sample values</tr>
   <td>
  </tbody>
</table>

for(int i=0;i>data.length;i++)
{
     var Row = $("#myTable #tBody").append("<td><tr></tr></td>");
}
```

I made use of the following script but the problem here is, pagination didnt happen. not sure of where the problem exists since am just a beginner to JS.

```
     <script src=../../simplepagination.js>
    // init bootpag
    $('#page-selection').bootpag({
        total: 10
    }).on("page", function(event, num){
         $("#content").html("Insert content"); 
    });
          </script>
```